# Arguments in Graphql query has no effect

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I am receiving one array, with 13.000 objects. I would like to make pagination with apollo-hooks, and set the limit to 10.

```
export const GET_PRODUCTS = gql`
  query GetProducts($type: String, $offset: Int, $limit: Int!) {
     products
      @rest(
        type: "Products"
        path: "/a-third-party-api"
      ) {
      productFeed(offset: $offset, limit: $limit) {
        productName
        productPrice
        productImage
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

This is returning 13.000 objects, and I did hope the limit variable would make it 10.

```
function MyComponent() {
  const { loading, error, data, fetchMore } = useQuery(GET_PRODUCTS, {
    variables: { type: "feed", offset: 0, limit: 10 },
    fetchPolicy: "cache-and-network",
  });

console.log(data)
...
}
```

It is worth mentioning, that it is a third party api, and I am using apollo-rest-link. The response is working just fine.

Is it possible to use the limit and make a pagination with a third party?

Comment: Does the API support pagination?

Comment: You can't add a query in the url that sets the limit, so no I don't think so

Comment: But how would you then handle a request on that size, to decrese the loading time?

Comment: if REST API supports pagination then inject some pagination variables into `path` string or use some fn in `pathBuilder` option